# Read bytes and its decimal value from any kind of file in C++

Tags: c++, file, decimal, ascii

This may have been answered before but I've tried several ways with no success.

What I need is to read all the bytes of any file type in C++ and access the decimal value of each byte.

```
Eg

some_file.txt
   ab¶

Expected outcome of each byte would be (in binary):
   01100001 01100010 11110100

Final result as a decimal (NEED THIS):
   97 98 244
```

---

```
some_file.bin
   01000001 01000010 11110100

Would have to read the 8 bits of each byte and return each value in decimal (NEED THIS)
   65 66 244
```

-

For the curious, I need the decimal to access the position of a heap that was assembled following the ASCII table to count the occurrence of each character.

---

EDIT - 
I have the following code to read any kind of file:

```
readFile.cpp

char* mem;
void readFile(char* file_name)
{
    ifstream::pos_type size;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(file_name, ios::binary|ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        size = file.tellg();
        mem = new char[size];
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file.read(mem, size);
        file.close();
        delete[] mem;
    }else{
        cout << "Not able to open the file";
    }
}

main.cpp

if(argc != 2) {
    exit(1);
}
char* fileName = argv[1];

readFile(fileName);

cout << mem[0] << " | dec: " << (int) (unsigned char) mem[0] << endl;
cout << mem[1] << " | dec: " << (int) (unsigned char) mem[1] << endl;
cout << mem[2] << " | dec: " << (int) (unsigned char) mem[2] << endl;
cout << mem[3] << " | dec: " << (int) (unsigned char) mem[3] << endl;
```

When the input file is something like "abc", the output is correct:

```
a | dec: 97
b | dec: 98
c | dec: 99
```

But when the input contains some extended ASCII char, the output gets crazy:

```
input = a¶aa

output = 
    a | dec: 97
    \ | dec: 92
    2 | dec: 50
    6 | dec: 54
```

Comment: oops!  I was in C# mode.  I'll fix my answer to C++ in a sec.

Comment: BTW you're deleting `mem` before you are done with it!

Comment: Does your file really contain extended ASCII or did you use a Unicode text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast through `unsigned char` (This works in C# too, using `char` or `byte`) to `int` to get the character code.  To the computer, it is just a number, no distinction between binary or decimal.

```
cout << mem[0] << " | dec: " << (int)(unsigned char)mem[0] << endl;
```

But you have to do this before you `delete[] mem`.  Consider using `vector<char>` or `std::string` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer @ben-voigt, but with the ASCII extended characters like ¶, the decimal returned by the cast isn't the right one.

Comment: Updated the question with one example.

Comment: @FladsonGomes: Sorry about giving C# code on a C++ question.  The problem with C++ is that signed-ness of `char` isn't specified, so bytes can be interpreted as negative.  The fix is pretty easy, see edit.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it still isn't the right decimal code, edited the question with your answer and the following output.

Comment: @Fladson: I just noticed you're printing data from freed memory -- you'll need to fix that also.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, but I'm editing the file in mac text editor and I saved it like plain text and the decimal code still not the right one  and for the record, I'm a complete noobie in C++, my main languages are Java and Ruby. Can you post a code answer plese?

Comment: In that context, "plain text" means no formatting like bold and underline. It doesn't mean ASCII.  So perhaps you aren't interested in the bytes after all, but the Unicode characters.

Comment: Thank you guys for all but I just need the decimal code for any ASCII character inside the 0 to 255 table, it's a compactor project so any kind of file could be the input, not just plain or unicode file, do anyone knows what is the best way to do this?

Comment: @FladsonGomes: The current code is giving you the value of every byte in the file.  You can only move from bytes to characters if you know the encoding.  Unfortunate facts of life.  For compression, working with bytes is probably ok.  And the "wrong" answer your C++ code was giving is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your file doesn't have the bytes you expect.  Your C++ code shows the content is

```
61 C2 B6 61
```

With the help of http://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html:

[image]

C++ is not wrong, those really *are* the bytes in the file.